# Return a named list with various elements from function call

Tags: r, function, return, apply

### Question

I have a function like this:

```
myfunc <- function(x){

    a1 = 1
    a2 = c(2,4)
    a3 = data.frame(x = 1:10)
    ...
    an = 'str'
    res = list(a1 = a1,a2 = a2,..., an=an)
    return(res)
}
```

As we can see, I return my results with a named list. However, if the number of elements is large, I cannot type `a_i = a_i` one by one. I use the code snippet below to save half of my time(**but I still need to type `"` around my elements' name, it's a waste of time**):

```
res_short = sapply(c('a1','a2',...,'an'),FUN = function(x){list(get(x))})
return(res_short)
```

Note that there may **not exist a pattern** in my elements' name `a1,a2,...,an`, I just use `a1`,`a2`...,`an` to be simplified.

I think I return with a named list is good, since list can store **different types of elements**. Is there any other methods to write my function return? I want to be **clear** and **time-saving**!

Comment: res_short = sapply(paste0("a",1:n),function(x){list(get(x))}) ?

Comment: But if you have to calculate a1.. an, you can just start by doing list(a1 =.., a2 = ..., a3 ..). Am I missing something important?

Comment: @StupidWolf thanks for your reply. Suppose I have 10 elements with complicated names, doing `list(a1=..,a2=..)` need type 'a1' twice and it's a waste of time I think.

Comment: No need for `return` in R — the last expression of a function is its return value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. **mget** Use `mget` as shown below.  To return all variables use `mget(ls())` or to return all variables except `x` use `mget(setdiff(ls(), "x"))`.  `ls` will not return object names that begin with a dot unless the `all` argument is used, i.e. `ls(all = TRUE)`, which could be used to prevent certain variables from being returned.  Another possibility is to use the `mode=` argument of `mget` to restrict the objects returned to ones that are `numeric`, say.  See `?mget`. Yet another approach to restrict the objects returned is to use `Filter` on the result of `mget`. For example, `res <- Filter(is.data.frame, mget(ls()))` only returns data frames.

   ```
   myfunc <- function(x){
       a1 = 1
       a2 = c(2,4)
       a3 = data.frame(x = 1:10)
       an = 'str'
       res = mget(ls(pattern = "^a"))
       return(res)
   }
   myfunc(3) # test
   ```
2. **environment** Another possibility is to return the environment within the executing function.  All objects in the function (not just the ones beginning with `a`) will be in the environment.

   ```
   myfunc2 <- function(x) {
       a1 = 1
       a2 = c(2,4)
       a3 = data.frame(x = 1:10)
       an = 'str'
       res = environment()
       return(res)
   }
   out <- myfunc2(3) # test
   out$a
   ```
3. **within** Another possibility is to use `within`.  Only variables created in the within will be returned. `x` is used in the `within` but not created in the `within` so it is not returned.

   ```
   myfunc3 <- function(x) {
     res <- within(list(), {
      a1 <- x
      a2 <- BOD
     })
     return(res)
   }
   myfunc3(3) # test
   ```
4. **Multiple ls**  Perform an `ls()` before and after the section creating the variables to be output and then `mget` the difference.

   ```
   myfunc4 <- function(x) {
     .excl <- ls()
     a1 <- x
     a2 <- BOD
     res <- mget(setdiff(ls(), .excl))
     return(res)
   }
   myfunc4(3) # test
   ```

Comment: Thanks! In a function, variable names should be meaningful, so there may not exist a pattern in variable names. If there is no pattern in elements' names, is there any way to figure this out?

Comment: I have to admit that I’ve used `as.list(environment())` myself in the past but I don’t like this solution, it’s undisciplined. I’d rather the code be explicit about which variables exactly it returns. `mget` is therefore better.

Comment: Have moved my comments to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, your requirements are very flexible. You have a bunch of variables with names that have no pattern. You want to apply a different computation for each variable. Well, you realize that you do need to type everything in at least once. One approach is to have a list of all possible variable names and their computations. You can then apply all of them, or a subset to your input. Here is an example for 3 names with 3 different computations.

```
mycomputer = list(
    add5 = function(x) {
        x + 5
    },
    mymean = function(x) {
        mean(x)
    },
    square = function(x) {
        x*x
    }
)
computeall = function(x) {
    result = lapply(names(mycomputer), function(f) {
        mycomputer[[f]](x)
    })
    names(result) = names(mycomputer)
    result
}

computeall(c(1,2,3))
## $add5
## [1] 6 7 8
## 
## $mymean
## [1] 2
## 
## $square
## [1] 1 4 9
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What I want is return a named list from function call . Each element has different name and type.If there are many elements , typing their name is time-wasting. However, you solution is apply several functions on a one input. Maybe my poor english misled you, sry for that

Comment: In my example you pass in your data to function computeall() and it returns a named list. No need to retype the names at that point. The names are typed in a single time, in function mycomputer(). Not sure how this is different from what you are asking.